# Unity3D's upcoming ECS vs current hierarchy

Tags: unity-game-engine, hierarchy, scenegraph, entity-component-system

#### Intro

I've been following Unity3D's DOTS development for a while now and I've been doing a few tutorials on getting ECS going. However, nowhere have I found it to be clear that Unity3D is deprecating their current GameObject/Hierarchy approach and replacing it with the new Entity/ECS approach.

#### Theories

At present, it seems like a hybrid between the two, so anything that typically belongs in a object pool or could cause memory fragmentation (projectiles, items, respawning units, etc.) uses Entity/ECS, and the rest still use GameObject/Hierarchy.

This seems less than ideal to me since the non-optimal approach will block going to the next frame where the optimal one will wait. Where if only ECS was used, you will get a lot more frames out, which is kinda the point...

On the other hand, having to onboard designers and animators to use something like ECS would just be expensive (**at the moment**) and much more technical. The current ECS window in the editor is not really intuitive and less a tool than simply a result output.

#### Question

So my question is, does Unity3D plan to keep the hybrid approach and if so, how do we choose whether to use an entity or a gameobject? Or if they are going with the ECS only approach, will the current entity editor window be changed to accommodate designers/animators?

Comment: They already stated in some of their developer videos they are keeping both the GameObject and DOTS.

Comment: @Eddge Ah! I must have missed that one. I'm going to see if I can find it.

Comment: Ok so after reviewing the Q&A session at the end of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QbnVELXf5RQ
There is mention of using the jobs system for either game objects or entities. Making ECS essentially optional to achieve multi-threading and its only real purpose seems to be for pooling and memory optimization.